# Is injecting a model into a service an anitipattern

Tags: robotlegs

Some services in my Robotlegs app require parameters. I'm wondering which solution is better:

1. Mediators pass parameters to services
2. Services aquire parameters from injected models

Comment: it depends on the type of parameters. Are they consts? Are they values from a model? Do they come from user input? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Creynders suggested, it depends on the scope of these variables, if they are const, model, or user input.

A great resource for me has been the ActionScript Developer's Guide to RobotLegs: http://books.google.ca/books/about/ActionScript_Developer_s_Guide_to_Robotl.html?id=PFA2TWqZdSMC&redir_esc=y

This is my usual workflow:

1. View dispatches a custom event and passes parameters to the event.
2. Mediator listens to the Event and re-dispatches it.
3. Context maps the event to a command.
4. Command injects the event, any necessary models, and the service.
5. Command calls the service, passing any necessary parameters. In the example below, I am passing a variable from the LoadLicenseEvent and from the ITokenModel to the service call. I use commandMap.detain() and commandMap.release() to keep the command alive until the service call is complete. The base class ServiceModuleCommand handles the fault event.

   ```
   public class LoadLicenseCommand extends ServiceModuleCommand
   {
       [Inject]
       public var event:LoadLicenseEvent;

       [Inject]
       public var service:ILicenseService;

       [Inject]
       public var tokenModel:ITokenModel;

       [Inject]
       public var licenseModel:ILicenseModel;

       public override function execute():void
       {
           commandMap.detain(this);

           var token:TokenVO = tokenModel.getToken();

           var asyncToken:AsyncToken = service.getLicense(token.Id, event.id);
           asyncToken.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(resultHandler, faultHandler));
       }

       private function resultHandler(e:ResultEvent):void
       {
           var license:LicenseWebViewVO = e.result as LicenseWebViewVO;
           if (license)
           {
               licenseModel.license = license;
               dispatchToModules(new RunWidgetEvent(WidgetType.getWidgetId(WidgetType.LICENSE)));
           }

           commandMap.release(this);
       }
   ```